# How to Select Category Name on the Basis of Id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am Using PHP, MYSQL. I have two tables

Table `posts` with following fields

```
id,
title,
body,
cat_id
```

Table `categories` with following fields

```
cat_id,
cat_name
```

Suppose, I have Following Data in `posts` table

```
id = 1
title = "This is Test Post"
body = "This is the Body of Test Pots"
cat_id = 3
```

and in `categories` table

```
cat_id = 3
cat_name = "Mobiles"
```

If I Use the Following SQL Statement

```
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=1";
```

It will give me following output

```
id = 1
title = "This is Test Post"
body = "This is the Body of Test Pots"
cat_id = 3
```

But I Want the Following Output

```
id = 1
title = "This is Test Post"
body = "This is the Body of Test Pots"
cat_id = Mobiles
```

How can I get the above mentioned output.

Note: I know some kind of `JOIN` is used in this kind of situation, But I don't know how to use it. One More thing, Is it possible to get my desired output without using any `JOIN`, because I heard that `JOINs` Effect the Efficiency. If `JOIN` is necessary Please tell me the most efficient Way to get my desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts JOIN categories USING (cat_id) WHERE posts.id = 1
```

It's possible to achieve the same using a [correlated subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/correlated-subqueries.html) instead (however this is likely to be [*less* efficient than a join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/rewriting-subqueries.html)):

```sql
SELECT *, (SELECT cat_name FROM categories WHERE cat_id = posts.cat_id)
FROM   posts
WHERE  id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) querty to join posts and categories in order to get informations from both tables. So you try with the following query

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.cat_name FROM posts as t1 join categories as t2 on t1.cat_id = t2.cat_id  WHERE t1.id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join query 
try this

```
SELECT id, title, body, cat_name FROM posts 
join categories on posts.cat_id = categories.cat_id  WHERE id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT post.id, post.title, post.body, cat.cat_name from posts inner
>   join categories  cat on cat.cat_id = post.cat_id
>   and post.id = 1

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to learn `JOINS` first read this articles

- **[JOINS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)**
- **[JOINS VS SUB-QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)**

now about your question checkout the

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36f298/3)**

```
SELECT * FROM posts As p
JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = p.cat_id
WHERE p.id = 1
```

now its your choice whether to use Joins or Sub-Queries both have its pros and cons
thus select as per your requirement.

hope this will help you ...!